# Disable/ enable dynamically input/ textarea/ select fields with jQuery

Tags: jquery, if-statement, input, addition

I have the following code with three options in a select box which should dynamically enable/disable the attribute "disable" in the input fields/ textarea / select, but the code doesn't work at all:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
$('.fieldcontent').not('.info').hide();
$('#selector_cs').change(function() {

      $('.fieldcontent').customFadeOut(100);
      $('.' + $(this).val()).customFadeIn(900);
     // $('input').prop('disabled',false);
    //$('textarea').prop('disabled',false);
    //$('select').prop('disabled',false);
 //option1
 if ($("this:selected").val() === 'help') {
$("textarea[name='message']").prop('disabled',false);
$("input[name='domain']").prop('disabled',false);
}else{
    $("textarea[name='message']").prop('disabled',true);
$("input[name='domain']").prop('disabled',true);
    };
    //option2
     if ($("this:selected").val() === 'info') {
$("textarea[name='message']").prop('disabled',false);

}else{
    $("textarea[name='message']").prop('disabled',true);
};
     //option3
     if ($("this:selected").val() === 'products') {
$("textarea[name='message']").prop('disabled',true);
$("select[name='products']").prop('disabled',false);
$("input[name='domain']").prop('disabled',false);
$("input[name='address']").prop('disabled',false);
$("input[name='state']").prop('disabled',false);
$("input[name='city']").prop('disabled',false);
$("input[name='country']").prop('disabled',false);
};      
});  });
```

Can anyone help me to write the code properly?

Thanks in advance for any help

**EDIT:** Thanks @Ken and @arun for the quick help. Now the jQuery is working.

But: I have a PHP validation which doesn't pass with the fiedls disabled by jQuery. Why?

Otherwise, i don't want to add/ remove dynamic hidden fields by jquery, because when the user receive a mail, he would see the hidden fields values, which aren't "real" values, but with values like "some1", "some2" ecc.

How to avoid this and using diasabled fields instead passing the php validation?

Comment: .attr('disabled', true)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your selector `$("this:selected").val()` is wrong, it should be `$(this).val()` to get the selected value

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.fieldcontent').not('.info').hide();
    $('#selector_cs').change(function() {

        $('.fieldcontent').customFadeOut(100);
        $('.' + $(this).val()).customFadeIn(900);
        // $('input').prop('disabled',false);
        //$('textarea').prop('disabled',false);
        //$('select').prop('disabled',false);
        //option1
        if ($(this).val() === 'help') {
            $("textarea[name='message']").prop('disabled',false);
            $("input[name='domain']").prop('disabled',false);
        }else{
            $("textarea[name='message']").prop('disabled',true);
            $("input[name='domain']").prop('disabled',true);
        };
        //option2
        if ($(this).val() === 'info') {
            $("textarea[name='message']").prop('disabled',false);

        }else{
            $("textarea[name='message']").prop('disabled',true);
        };
        //option3
        if ($(this).val() === 'products') {
            $("textarea[name='message']").prop('disabled',true);
            $("select[name='products']").prop('disabled',false);
            $("input[name='domain']").prop('disabled',false);
            $("input[name='address']").prop('disabled',false);
            $("input[name='state']").prop('disabled',false);
            $("input[name='city']").prop('disabled',false);
            $("input[name='country']").prop('disabled',false);
        };      
    }); 
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/FL6tn/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Changing $("this:selected").val() to $(this).val() should fix your issue

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.fieldcontent').not('.info').hide();

    $('#selector_cs').change(function () {
        $('.fieldcontent').customFadeOut(100);
        $('.' + $(this).val()).customFadeIn(900);

        // $('input').prop('disabled',false);
        //$('textarea').prop('disabled',false);
        //$('select').prop('disabled',false);
        //option1

        if ($(this).val() === 'help') {
            $("textarea[name='message']").prop('disabled', false);
            $("input[name='domain']").prop('disabled', false);
        } else {
            $("textarea[name='message']").prop('disabled', true);
            $("input[name='domain']").prop('disabled', true);
        }

        //option2
        if ($(this).val() === 'info') {
            $("textarea[name='message']").prop('disabled', false);

        } else {
            $("textarea[name='message']").prop('disabled', true);
        }

        //option3
        if ($(this).val() === 'products') {
            $("textarea[name='message']").prop('disabled', true);
            $("select[name='products']").prop('disabled', false);
            $("input[name='domain']").prop('disabled', false);
            $("input[name='address']").prop('disabled', false);
            $("input[name='state']").prop('disabled', false);
            $("input[name='city']").prop('disabled', false);
            $("input[name='country']").prop('disabled', false);
        }
    });
});
```